# Need to prepend a string to a column and to add another column with it

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with 2 lines

```
123|456|789
abc|123|891
```

I need a to output like below. Basically, I want to add the string "xyz" to col 1 and to add "xyz" as a new col 2

```
xyz-123|xyz|456|789
xyz-abc|xyz|123|891
```

This is what I used

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs-"$1}{print value OFS $0}' /tmp/b.log
```

I get

```
xyz-123|456|789
xyz-abc|123|891
```

I tried

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs-"$1}{print value OFS $0}' /tmp/b.log|awk -F" " '{$2="fs" $0;}1' OFS=" "
```

Comment: Your example script you tried and your output you get do not match! You use the string "fs-" but your output returns "xyz-". The way you define your field separators `FS=OFS="fs-"$1` in the `BEGIN` block, is equivalent to `FS=OFS="fs-"` as `$1` does not exist and, hence, is an empty string `""` . The variable `value` is undefined, and therefore an empty string `""`. So since `OFS="fs-"`, your print statement actually just prints `"fs-" $0`, which explains your output.

Comment: The following will do what you want : `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$1="xyz-" $1 OFS "xyz"}1' file` or with a variable: `awk -v s="xyz" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$1= s "-" $1 OFS s}1' file`

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$1="xyz-"$1;$2="xyz" OFS $2} 1' Input_file
```

OR as per @Corentin Limier's comment try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$1="xyz-" $1 OFS "xyz"} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
xyz-123|xyz|456|789
xyz-abc|xyz|123|891
```

Comment: Unlike any of the posted sed solutions, this will work even when your added strings contain `&` or other backreference metacharacers or sed delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the awk's updating fields ($1, $2...) approach, we can also use substitution to do the job:

```
 sed 's/^[^|]*/xyz-&|xyz/' file
```

If awk is a must:

```
awk '1+sub(/^[^|]*/, "xyz-&|xyz")' file
```

Both one-liners give expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I would use **sed** instead of **awk** as follows:

```
sed -e 's/^/xyz-/' -e 's/|/|xyz|/' Input_file
```

This prepends `xyz-` at beginning of each line and changes the first `|` into `|xyz|`

Comment: The `|` does not need to be escaped in single quotes; indeed this script gives the wrong output (`sed (GNU sed) 4.8`).

Comment: Look at mine, where I've saved a few characters by joining the 2 `s` commands in one string. Howevere, the best answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59883365/5825294).

Answer (score 0):

Another slight variation of `sed`:

```
sed 's/^/xyz-/;s/|/&xyz&/' file
```

Comment: Or `sed 's/^/xyz-/;s/|/|xyz|/' file` because using a constant as `|` is usually faster than using a variable like `&`